# Naming KendoUI control with ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I'm trying to name my KendoUI grid with ViewBag.ModuleId and i'm getting error. How do i do it properly.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TimeSheetSummaryViewModel>()
    .Name("grid-timesheetsummary-" + ViewBag.ModuleId)
    .DataSource(datasource => datasource.Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetReport", "Reporting"))
    )
    .AutoBind(true)
)
```

Visual Studio shows red curly on Ajax() saying "Cannot resolve symbol Ajax"

Comment: What's the error you are getting ?

Comment: Visual Studio shows red curly on Ajax() saying "Cannot resolve symbol Ajax"

Comment: I this only when you put `ViewBag.ModuleId` in the code ?

Comment: Yes. It appear only if i add "+ ViewBag.ModuleId"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution by casting it to (string)

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TimeSheetSummaryViewModel>()
    .Name("grid-timesheetsummary-" + (String) ViewBag.ModuleId)
    .DataSource(datasource => datasource.Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetTimeSheetSummary", "Reporting"))
    )
    .AutoBind(true)
)
```